# Defining an array using define directive in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm new here and I'd like some help.

My code

```
#define ASDF "548896"
```

Does this mean that ASDF can be used as an array?

What will be the output of `ASDF[0 % sizeof(ASDF) ]` ?

Comment: It's the same as `"548896"[0 % sizeof("548896")]`

Comment: Which is the same as `"548896"[0]`

Comment: OK so if we evaluate the [] bracket does it mean it's "548896" [0]?  And therefore outputting 5 as an answer since it'll be 0th index?

Comment: Have you actually tried to run such code past a compiler to see what it does?

Comment: This isn't the full code. The full code is giving weird output as to the one it's supposed to

Comment: Then perhaps you should post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the actual problem you're having.

Comment: Thanks guys I got my answer. Love you all.. Love this community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocessor simply perform token replacement, it doesn't detail with data types. Since the expansion of `ASDF` is a string literal, it can be used anywhere that a string literal is allowed, and the result will be exactly the same as if you'd written the literal itself. So

```
ASDF[0 % sizeof(ASDF) ]
```

is equivalent to

```
"548896"[0 % sizeof("548896")]
```

`"548896"` is `7` (6 bytes in the string, plus a null terminator byte), so this is the same as

```
"548896"[0 % 7]
```

And since `0 % anything` is just `0`, it's equivalent to

```
"548896"[0]
```

which is the character `'5'`.

I expect most compilers will perform all these transformations at compile time, so if you write that original expression it will be compiled as if you'd written `'5'` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessing is *conceptually* a prior phase of C compilation (and even before the parsing phase of the compiler).

So you should consider that the compiler proper is getting preprocessed code. In the old times (1980s) the preprocessor was even a different program (`/lib/cpp`).

Today, you can still ask for the preprocessed form `mysource.i` of your source code `mysource.c` e.g. by compiling it with `gcc -C -E mysource.c > mysource.i` if using the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler.

So what the compiler is (conceptually) parsing for your example is:

```
 "548896"[0 % sizeof("548896")]
```

which is equivalent to `"548896"[0 % (size_t)7]`  which is same as `"548896"[0]` which can be simplified to `'5'` which, on my Linux system using UTF-8, is the same as `(char)53`